# Look for a certain character in another character and determine its starting point

Tags: java, char

I should create a method that determines if a character appears in another character. If it doesn't I wanna return -1 else I should return the point when the character we looked for appeared the 1st time (the starting point).
Our examples are:

```
char [] text1 = {'x','x','H','U','G', 'O',
              'H','U', 'G', 'O', 'x',
                'H','U', 'G', 'O', 'x', 'x'}; 
                char [] text2 = {'x','x','H','U','G', 'O'}; 
                
                char [] search = {'H','U', 'G', 'O'};
```

Here the goal is to receive 2 or 3 (whether you start counting by 0 or 1) in both cases text1 and text2.
What I have is:

```
static int find(char[] text, char[] searchText, int fromPos) {
        if (text == null) return -1;
        if (text.length == 0) return -1;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = fromPos; i<text.length; i++) {
            if (text[i] == searchText[j]) return i;
            j++;
        } return -1;
}
```

But it doesn't really work and I get an OutofBounds Exception. int fromPos = 0 btw

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure if this is allowed in your requirements but I could give you a simple solution by converting the array to string then using it's methods.

```
static int find(char[] text, char[] searchText, int fromPos) {

    if (searchText == null || text == null || text.length < 1 || searchText.length < 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    String searchString = new String(searchText);
    String textString = new String(text);

    if (!textString.contains(searchString)) {
        return -1;
    }
    
    return textString.indexOf(searchString);
    
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's allowed, but it's always good when the code works and your code works, so if I can't find another solution I will go with yours. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are incrementing `j` without stopping when `j` is larger then the length of search text and that is causing `OutofBounds Exception`

You are wanting to find the position where all the following chars are the same as the searchText. I think the problem is you are trying to iterate over `text` and `searchText` at the same time and this is causing the loop not to check as intended.

```
static int find(char[] text, char[] searchText, int fromPos) {
    if (text == null) return -1;
    if (text.length == 0) return -1;
    for (int i = fromPos; i < text.length - searchText.length; i++) {
        boolean isSame = true;
        for (int j = 0; j < searchText.length; j++){
            isSame = isSame && (text[i + j] == searchText[j]);
        }
        if (isSame){
            return i;
        }
    } return -1;
}
```

This will go over each char in text, in position `i` which will first be the value of `fromPos`, and check if it is the same as `searchText[j]`, `j` starting at zero.

```
isSame = isSame && (text[i + j] == searchText[i]);
```

is the same as

```
if(!text[i + j] == searchText[i]){
    isSame = false;
}
```

Comment: Hey thx for your answer, when I use your code the compiler says: "variable j is already defined in method find (char...)" We use j twice, how do we fix this?

Comment: My bad I meant to remove int j = 0, I will fix it now.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried that and it compiles succesfully but I have an OutOfBoundsException then.

Comment: What value does it say is out of bounds?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 4 out of bounds for length 4
 at Texter.find(Texter.java:55)
 at Texter.main(Texter.java:24)
This is row 55: isSame = isSame && (text[i + j] == searchText[i]);     row 24 is where the method is applied

Comment: My bad, I used j instead of i I will fix it now